# Using providers of a lazy-loaded module in components of other modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

In my app I have 2 modules which have their own sets of components and providers. One of two modules is required only in certain circumstances, for example, if a user has special permission, so I'd like to make this module lazy-loaded. The problem is that another module, which is eagerly loaded, utilizes some services and component from the module that can be lazy-loaded, and it generates errors, because the normal module and its components know nothing about components and services of the lazy-loaded module. Making those services and components (of lazy-loaded module) shared would defy the main purpose of making the module lazy-loaded — to decrease size of the app. What are the viable solutions in this case?